# VFP indexing and saving with INDEX ON while CDX exists

Tags: database, indexing, format, visual-foxpro, dbf

Working with VFP 9, I've indexed a DBF file by `group` (a column in the DBF) using

```
 INDEX ON group TO group1
```

and the records are in correct order. But then, **whenever I close and reopen the DBF, the indexing is lost (no order by `group`)**. I've found a .CDX file on the same folder, as my group.idx and the dbf, and it looks like it's giving a structure to the DBF but I dont know how to change it or see it.

To solve this issue I erased the CDX file (of course an error pop-up because it could not find the .cdx) and used the `COPY TO` function to keep the indexed DBF but this is not a real solution for the issue (which is a solution mentioned in a forum, but it doesnt seem the best approach to me).
I've also tried to use the `PACK` function at the end, just before closing the database but didnt work to keep the dataset indexed.

Besides the above mentioned, I've couldn't find any  answer to this particular issue on the web, so I really appreciate any comment to help me understand it and to resolve the indexing while coding, and of course making sure the index and changes will stay put whenever closing the database. Many thanks in advance!

*Additional Question:* usually when I index I give a name to the IDX file created but when working with similar DBFs I repeat the coding, and index on diferent tables with the same idx name (so I overwrite the .idx each time, thinking it has no use anymore), but I really don't know if this may cause me problems in the future.

***Update:*** Though I couldn't solve the issue directly for a specific DBF using the indexing and order commands, I used the `COPY TO` command and then replace manually the new dbf with the old one.

This might be of interestto begginers like me: http://www2.hkedcity.net/sch_files/a/tps/tps-comp/visitor_cabinet/123570/db-ch05.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IDX is usually not recommended. In order to get a CDX (compound index) use this slightly different syntax ("TAG" instead of "TO"):

`INDEX ON group TAG group1`

I would also recommend against using "group" as a field/column name since it is a reserved word in VFP.

Comment: Such an easy solution! Thanks a lot Steve! I've just tried out, it goes smooth. By the way, does the order still in place if I delete the CDX after running a program on the DBF??

Comment: Cheers. Also see Herb Wolfe's addition below as well.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to using the `INDEX ON group TAG group1` command, when you (re-) open the file, you need to select the index. This can be done in one of two ways.

Either

```
USE filename
SET ORDER TO group1
```

or

```
USE filename ORDER TAG group1
```

Comment: Thanks Herb! Is there a way to open the DBF already with the order set? because I want it to keep the same order as I had since last program runned on the dbf. @Steve

Comment: Nope. No method did the trick for this dbf (it did for others), I tried both methods you propose using TAG and TO (not at the same time of course) but the dbf keeps reseting itself. I dont know why the order doesn't hold after I close it. any chance there's a structure panel or an editable option someone might have changed in this dbf?

Comment: As before I "solved" the issue by opening the dbf, setting the order and then using `COPY TO` to save the dbf with a similar name and thus overwrite the dbf manualy... I posted this question because of that at the beggining but it's just some DBFs, not all, and of course I checked a million times.